# Finding duplicate rows in Oracle based on 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this SQL query:

```
Select OS_PRZU.KUNR,
  OS_PRZU.IDNR,
  OS_PRZU.PRL_NR,
  OS_PRZU.ZUM2
From OS_PRZU OS_PRZU
Order By OS_PRZU.KUNR,
  OS_PRZU.IDNR,
  OS_PRZU.PRL_NR
```

I need to find duplicate rows where `OS_PRZU.KUNR` and `OS_PRZU.IDNR` are the same.

Looking online I see examples about matching where all columns are the same but this doesn't seem to help me.

What is simplest method to achieve this output?

Comment: Add this to you code: `WHERE OS_PRZU.KUNR = OS_PRZU.IDNR`

Comment: @KinchitDalwani I think you have misunderstood the question? I want to match rows not columns.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

To get all the rows (without using an expensive self-join) you can use the [`COUNT() OVER ()` analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT KUNR,
         IDNR,
         PRL_NR,
         ZUM2,
         COUNT(1) OVER ( PARTITION BY KUNR, IDNR ) AS num_rows
  FROM   OS_PRZU
)
WHERE  num_rows > 1
ORDER BY
       KUNR,
       IDNR,
       PRL_NR;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select   OS_PRZU.KUNR,
         OS_PRZU.IDNR
From     OS_PRZU OS_PRZU
group by OS_PRZU.KUNR,
         OS_PRZU.IDNR
having   count(1) > 1
```

If you want all your original attributes as well, you can simply join it back:

```
Select OS_PRZU.KUNR,
  OS_PRZU.IDNR,
  OS_PRZU.PRL_NR,
  OS_PRZU.ZUM2
From OS_PRZU OS_PRZU
inner join (
            Select   OS_PRZU.KUNR,
                     OS_PRZU.IDNR
            From     OS_PRZU OS_PRZU
            group by OS_PRZU.KUNR,
                     OS_PRZU.IDNR
            having   count(1) > 1
           ) dups
      on   dups.KUNR = OS_PRZU.KUNR
      and  dups.IDNR = OS_PRZU.IDNR
Order By OS_PRZU.KUNR,
  OS_PRZU.IDNR,
  OS_PRZU.PRL_NR
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `OS_PRZU.KUNR / OS_PRZU.IDNR` combinations that appear more than once with something like

```
select  KUNR, IDNR
from    OS_PRZU
group by KUNR, IDNR
having   count(*) > 1
```

You can then join that with the original table

```
select  t1.KUNR, t1.IDNR, t1.PRL_NR, t1.ZUM2
from    OS_PRZU t1
join    (
            select  KUNR, IDNR
            from    OS_PRZU
            group by KUNR, IDNR
            having   count(*) > 1
        ) t2
on      t1.KUNR = t2.KUNR and
        t1.IDNR = t2.IDNR
order by t1.KUNR, t1.IDNR, t1.PRL_NR
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [HoneyBadger's earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44024619/1509264)

Comment: @MT0 his edit with the self join came later than my answer